# Calculating values from time series in pandas multi-indexed pivot tables

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I've got a dataframe in pandas that stores the Id of a person, the quality of interaction, and the date of the interaction. A person can have multiple interactions across multiple dates, so to help visualise and plot this I converted it into a pivot table grouping first by Id then by date to analyse the pattern over time.

e.g.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Id':['A4G8','A4G8','A4G8','P9N3','P9N3','P9N3','P9N3','C7R5','L4U7'],
                   'Date':['2016-1-1','2016-1-15','2016-1-30','2017-2-12','2017-2-28','2017-3-10','2019-1-1','2018-6-1','2019-8-6'],
                   'Quality':[2,3,6,1,5,10,10,2,2]})
pt = df.pivot_table(values='Quality', index=['Id','Date'])
print(pt)
```

Leads to this:

| Id | Date | Quality |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A4G8 | 2016-1-1 | 2 |
|  | 2016-1-15 | 4 |
|  | 2016-1-30 | 6 |
| P9N3 | 2017-2-12 | 1 |
|  | 2017-2-28 | 5 |
|  | 2017-3-10 | 10 |
|  | 2019-1-1 | 10 |
| C7R5 | 2018-6-1 | 2 |
| L4U7 | 2019-8-6 | 2 |

However, I'd also like to...

1. Measure the time from the first interaction for each interaction per Id
2. Measure the time from the previous interaction with the same Id

So I'd get a table similar to the one below

| Id | Date | Quality | Time From First | Time To Prev |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A4G8 | 2016-1-1 | 2 | 0 days | NA days |
|  | 2016-1-15 | 4 | 14 days | 14 days |
|  | 2016-1-30 | 6 | 29 days | 14 days |
| P9N3 | 2017-2-12 | 1 | 0 days | NA days |
|  | 2017-2-28 | 5 | 15 days | 15 days |
|  | 2017-3-10 | 10 | 24 days | 9 days |

The Id column is a string type, and I've converted the date column into datetime, and the Quality column into an integer.

The column is rather large (>10,000 unique ids) so for performance reasons I'm trying to avoid using for loops. I'm guessing the solution is somehow using pd.eval but I'm stuck as to how to apply it correctly.

Apologies I'm a python, pandas, & stack overflow) noob and I haven't found the answer anywhere yet so even some pointers on where to look would be great :-).
Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert `Date`s to datetimes and then substract minimal datetimes per groups by [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html)b subtracted by column `Date` and for second new column use [`DataFrameGroupBy.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff.html):

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
   
df['Time From First'] = df['Date'].sub(df.groupby('Id')['Date'].transform('min'))
df['Time To Prev'] = df.groupby('Id')['Date'].diff()
print (df)
     Id       Date  Quality Time From First Time To Prev
0  A4G8 2016-01-01        2          0 days          NaT
1  A4G8 2016-01-15        3         14 days      14 days
2  A4G8 2016-01-30        6         29 days      15 days
3  P9N3 2017-02-12        1          0 days          NaT
4  P9N3 2017-02-28        5         16 days      16 days
5  P9N3 2017-03-10       10         26 days      10 days
6  P9N3 2019-01-01       10        688 days     662 days
7  C7R5 2018-06-01        2          0 days          NaT
8  L4U7 2019-08-06        2          0 days          NaT
```

Comment: Please, take the time to reformat post of new contributor as you answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
df = df.merge(
    df.groupby(["Id"]).Date.first(),
    on="Id",
    how="left",
    suffixes=["", "_first"]
)
df["Time From First"] = df.Date-df.Date_first
df['Time To Prev'] = df.groupby('Id').Date.diff()
df.set_index(["Id", "Date"], inplace=True)
df
```

output:

[image]